# How to lowercase the values of a table to use filter

Tags: jquery

I would like to lowercase the values of a table so i would be able to use my filter to search trough these values and only show the desired rows.

Code:

```
$(".company-filter").keyup(function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var tableRows = $(".filter-body>tr").show();
    var data = thisVal.split(" ");
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        tableRows.filter(':not(:contains(' + val + '))').hide();
    });
});
```

I searched, learned and know how to do it for the input but i have now idea how to do it for my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.filter(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

```
tableRows.filter(function() {
    //':not(:contains(' + val + '))' 
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) == -1;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But for me this is difficult to read and by that difficult to understand. I for example never saw the usage of indexOf in such format. Could you explain this line a little more?

Comment: @Peter Javascript has no string `.contains()` method, so `.indexOf()` is used as a replacement. It returns `-1` if the argument is not found in the original string. (Also, it always returns an integer, so you should use `===` rather than `==`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#whatever {text-transform:lowercase;}
```

in CSS, try that if your jQuery isn't working. You can do it through the jQuery, modify the CSS through the jQuery.

Hope it helped or gave you any idea. Good luck! ;)

Comment: This only transforms the way the browser will render the text. Any javascript that accesses it will only ever use the non-transformed value

Comment: Oh, true. Thank you very much! ;) +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

What @Satpal suggests is cleaner and you should go with that. If you're dead set on redoing your text, however, here's how to do it:

```
$(".filter-body td").text(function(idx, str) {
    return str.toLowerCase();
});
```